# OMNeT++ send routing table in packet

Tags: c++, omnet++

I need to send the entire routing table in a packet with OMNeT++. 
MyPacket.msg file is this:

```
cplusplus {{
#include "inet/networklayer/ipv4/IPv4RoutingTable.h"
#include "inet/networklayer/contract/ipv4/IPv4Address.h"
}}

namespace inet;

class noncobject inet::IPv4RoutingTable;
class noncobject inet::IPv4Address;

packet MyPacket    {
   IPv4Address srcIPAddress;
   IPv4RoutingTable rt;
}
```

but when I build the project, I get these errors:

> use of deleted function ‘inet::IPv4RoutingTable& inet::IPv4RoutingTable::operator=(const inet::IPv4RoutingTable&)’
>   use of deleted function ‘inet::IPv4RoutingTable& inet::IPv4RoutingTable::operator=(const inet::IPv4RoutingTable&)’
>   use of deleted function ‘cSimpleModule& cSimpleModule::operator=(const cSimpleModule&)’ IPv4RoutingTable.h
>   use of deleted function ‘cNoncopyableOwnedObject& cNoncopyableOwnedObject::operator=(const cNoncopyableOwnedObject&)’
>   use of deleted function ‘cModule& cModule::operator=(const cModule&)’
>   use of deleted function ‘cDefaultList& cDefaultList::operator=(const cDefaultList&)’
>   use of deleted function ‘cComponent& cComponent::operator=(const cComponent&)’
>   ‘const noncopyable& noncopyable::operator=(const noncopyable&)’ is private

how can I solve this? thanks!

Comment: You cannot send routing table this way, because `IPv4RoutingTable` is a simple module placed somewhere in the host. And simple module cannot be directly copied into another host. You should consider rewriting all entries of routing table into own structure and adding this structure into own packet.

Comment: @JerzyD. thanks a lot for this tip! I solved creating a structure